# Need help replicating a little bit of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

I am working on some basic JavaScript.

I have a muse website and I'm using this script so users can enter a specific password and be redirected to a page, I need to be able to change this so I can do this multiple times, so: multiple passwords going multiple places.

For example, when users click a button they are asked for a password, when they enter `CUSTOMPASSWORD1` they will be redirected to `mywebsite.com/custompassword1.html` how would I edit this script so that they could also type in `CUSTOMPASSWORD2` and be redirected to `mywebsite.com/custompassword2.html`?

Script below:

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Enter Store Code Here',' ');
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1) 
      history.go(-1);
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "CUSTOMPASSWORD1234") {
      alert('You are being redirected!');
      window.open('CUSTOMPASSWORD1234.html');
      break;
    } 
    testV+=1;
    var pass1 = 
    prompt('Access Denied - Store Code Not Recognised, Please Try Again.','Password');
  }
  if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
  history.go(-1);
  return " ";
} 
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Enter Store Code" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>
```

Comment: Ouch, that hurts to see passwords in javascript. You know a user can just view source and see them right? Why not just have a link?

Comment: Sorry I dont really use javascript that much, Its not necessarily meant to be hidden, im simply "misusing" this tool; so that when a user enters in a code such as "123456" they are redirected to "mywebsite.com/123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, I think you could just do this:

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Enter Store Code Here',' ');
while (testV < 3) {
if (!pass1) 
history.go(-1);
if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "CUSTOMPASSWORD1234") {
alert('You are being redirected!');
window.open('CUSTOMPASSWORD1234.html');
break;
} 
else if (pass1.toUpperCase() == "CUSTOMPASSWORD2"){
window.open('CUSTOMPASSWORD2.html');
break;
}

testV+=1;
var pass1 = 
prompt('Access Denied - Store Code Not Recognised, Please Try Again.','Password');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
history.go(-1);
return " ";
} 
</SCRIPT>
<CENTER>
<FORM>
<input type="button" value="Enter Store Code" onClick="passWord()">
</FORM>
</CENTER>
```

You also have what I assume is an error with

```
(pass1.toLowerCase() == "CUSTOMPASSWORD1234")
```

since this will never evaluate to true since CUSTOMPASSWORD1234 is upper case. Also you don't have an evaluation for CUSTOMPASSWORD1.

It seems like you're lacking in basic JS and programming knowledge so I'd recommend reading some basic tutorial in programming concepts before you start building stuff. Just hacking together tutorials will make spaghetti code and you won't learn.

Trent's answer is better design which you should use, this answer is just how to specifically implement what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help, it has worked! I'm really new to it, I just needed this little bit of java script to get my project over the line.

Comment: If it worked well, please upvote it and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to do is simply redirect the user to whichever url they enter in the prompt.

To achieve that, we can use a similar approach:

```js
function redirect() {
  var pass1 = prompt('Enter Store Code Here', ' ');
  if (!pass1) {
    history.go(-1);
  } else {
    alert('You are being redirected!');
    window.open(pass1 + '.html');
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Enter Store Code" onClick="redirect()">
  </form>
</center>
```